# Attention does not seem to be applied at TransformerEncoderLayer and MultiheadAttention PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

Changing something at one position in my input does not affect the outputs at other positions of my transformer encoder. I made a test in isolation in PyTorch:

```
# My encoder layer
encoder_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=8, nhead=2)
# Turn off dropout
encoder_layer.eval()
# Random input
src = torch.rand(2, 10, 8)
# Predict the output
out_0 = encoder_layer(src)
# Change the values at one of the positions (position 3 in this case)
src[:,3,:] += 1
# Predict once again the output
out_1 = encoder_layer(src)
# Check at which positions the outcomes are different between the two cases
# I summed in the embedding space direction
print(np.sum(np.abs(out_0.detach().numpy()),axis=-1) - np.sum(np.abs(out_1.detach().numpy()),axis=-1))
```

Output:

```
[[ 0. 0.  0.  -0.15470695  0.   0. 0.  0.     0.  0.   ]
 [ 0.   0.  0.  -0.27988768  0.  0.0.   0.   0.   0.   ]]
```

However, this does work in TensorFlow:

```
# My encoder layer
encoder_layer = TransformerBlock(8, 2, 8)
# Random input
src = np.random.randn(2, 10, 8)
# Predict the output
out_0 = encoder_layer(src, training=False)
# Change the values at one of the positions (position 3 in this case)
src[:,3,:] += 1
# Predict once again the output
out_1 = encoder_layer(src, training=False)
# Check at which positions the outcomes are different between the two cases
# I summed in the embedding space direction
print(np.sum(np.abs(out_0),axis=-1) )
```

Output:

```
[[6.4196725 6.775745  6.946576  7.26213   6.473065  5.520765  6.201167
  7.1266503 6.3147016 6.614853 ]
 [5.565378  7.030789  6.768366  6.6065626 6.7277775 7.480627  6.6785836
  6.4560523 6.4248576 6.6436586]]
```

My question is: Why aren't the values at all the position affected by changing the input at one input in PyTorch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.TransformerEncoderLayer.html):

- **batch_first** – If `True`, then the input and output tensors are provided as (batch, seq, feature). Default: `False`.

In other words, your input are 10 8-dimensional batches of sequence length 2 each. What you are doing is add 1 to all dimensions of all inputs of sample #4 in the batch, which --unsurprisingly-- alters only the output values of that specific sample.